# Migrate Azure Devops organization to another enterprise

Tags: azure-devops, enterprise, account, migrate, organization

I created two organizations on Azure Devops using two differents enterprise emails. I would like to migrate one of the organization to the other enterprise. I need to migrate everything (users, codes, backlog, processes, etc.).

*Screenshot from my profil on dev.azure.com*
[image]
Anybody knows how to do that, if even possible?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just dealt with something similar last week. After spending a month going back and forth with Azure support, we found Azure does not have any interface support for transferring subscriptions between enterprise accounts (at the time of writing this answer, at least).

I would recommend opening an Azure support ticket asking to transfer the organization between the enterprise accounts, then coordinate with the Azure support team, who will hopefully transfer the organization somehow on the backend.

Comment: Thx I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called the *Azure DevOps Migration Tools*, developed by a Scottish consultancy [NkdAgility](https://nkdagility.com/) that will do most, if not all of what you are wanting. We are migrating from one Azure DevOps organisation to another organisation and moving the work items, areas, sprints, backlog, git, etc.

Some helpful links on this toolset

- [documentation](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) on github
- [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCJsST0xBCE&feature=youtu.be) intro to using the tool
- WorkItem migration [parameter list](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Processors/WorkItemMigrationConfig.html)
- Some [SO questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops-migration-tools) to using this tool